# Moving both text and icons from one JTextPane to another

Tags: java, chat, jtextpane

I'm currently making a GUI for a chat room. I've made it so the user enters text and can pick images that end up in a JTextPane. After the user presses enter I want to display it in another JTextPane though. Is there an easy way to move both text and icons from one JTextPane to another at the same time? I've only managed to move one of them at a time.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  I don’t understand what it means to “move” text or icons.  What is preventing you from simply adding the same content to another JTextPane?

Comment: I've got a keylistener on the JTextPane where the user writes text or add images. When the user press enter I want the content of that JTextPane to move to another JTextPane. I'm not sure how to get all the content from a JTextPane to another JTextPane, not just text or icons by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [ElementIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/ElementIterator.html) to copy over a JTextPane’s StyledDocument element by element, with all styling, including icons:

```
static void copy(Document source,
                 Document dest) {
    try {
        dest.remove(0, dest.getLength());

        ElementIterator iterator = new ElementIterator(source);
        Element element;
        while ((element = iterator.next()) != null) {
            if (element.isLeaf()) {
                int start = element.getStartOffset();
                int end = element.getEndOffset();
                String text = source.getText(start, end - start);
                dest.insertString(dest.getLength(), text, 
                    element.getAttributes());
            }
        }
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```